# How to attach a UINavigationController subclass to its UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, subclass

I create a UINavigationController subclass:

```
class CustomNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

    var imageview:UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: self.navigationBar.frame.width, height: self.navigationBar.frame.height+20))
        imageview.image = UIImage(named: "navbar")
        self.navigationBar.addSubview(imageview)
    }
 }
```

In my storyboard, I set the UINavigationController as CustomNavigationViewController.

[image]

At run, my image in the navigationBar is correctly displayed.

But, I don't know how to make a reference to the CustomNavigationViewController in my HomeViewController class. I need to access to its imageview variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HomeViewController`'s `navigationController` property already pointing to the same object when `HomeViewcontroller` is pushed into that `CustomNavigationViewController`. Just cast it into `CustomNavigationViewController`

Code

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if let customNavigation = self.navigationController as? CustomNavigationViewController {
       // here you got your `customNavigationController`'s object. 
       customNavigation.imageview // access it
    }
}
```

NB: Do not try to access the `navigationController` property of `UIViewController`, because in that time it won't be holding the navigation controller yet.

Comment: I think you miss "as? CustomNavigationViewController" in your answer.

Comment: Yes i missed it, i've updated the answer, please check.